# Cooks distance and categorical features

Tags: r, regression, outliers, cooks-distance

I try to detect outliers by cook´s distance for a regression. If I only use numeric features as explanatory variables it works fine. However, if I add categorical features to the explanatory features I get some NA values.  Has that something to do with the measure? I have no NA/NaN/Inf values in the data set. Even if I transform the categorical features into dummy variables there is no change.

Here is an example (The dataset has 1460 obs and 83 variables so I can´t create a dput of the whole data):

```
library(dplyr)
```

Checking NA/Inf/NaN:

```
any(is.na(out))
[1] FALSE

any(sapply(out,is.infinite))
[1] FALSE

any(sapply(out,is.nan))
[1] FALSE
```

Calculating Cook´s distance for numerics:

```
out_num = out %>% select_if(is.numeric)

mod = lm(SalePrice~., data = out_num)

cooksd = cooks.distance(mod)

is.na(cooksd) %>% table()

FALSE 
1460
```

Calculating Cook´s distance for all data:

```
out

mod = lm(SalePrice~., data = out)

cooksd = cooks.distance(mod)

is.na(cooksd) %>% table()

FALSE  TRUE 
1441    19
```

If I calculate the diagnostic plots I get the following message:

```
plot(mod, which = 2) # or 
plot(mod, which = 3)
not plotting observations with leverage one:
121, 272, 326, 347, 376, 399, 584, 596, 667, 811, 822, 
1004, 1012, 1188, 1231, 1271, 1276, 1299, 1322, 1371, 1387

plot(mod, which = 4)
NaNs produced
```

This may have something to do with it but I did´t found the reason yet.

Comment: Cooks distance is defined even when categorical variables are included, so it sounds like a problem with your code. Can you share a minimal example of that?